# SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR: relation "migrations" already exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

- Laravel Version: 5.1
- PHP Version:5.6
- Database Driver & Version: psql

#### Description:

I run `php artisan migrate` the first time, and it work perfectly fine.

#### Then:

I've added 1 more migration script to **alter** one of my table.

---

As soon as I ran `php artisan migrate`,  I started to see this error.

[image]

---

I have this setting in my **database.php**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),


'pgsql'       => [
    'driver'      => 'pgsql',
    'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
    'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'     => 'utf8',
    'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'      => '',
    'strict'      => false,
    ],
```

Please kindly let me know what else, I can provide.

Comment: did you do migrate:rollback command ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't need to do that right now.

Comment: Then remove it manually from your database

Comment: I run it the first time, and it work fine. It added all the schemas. Then, I added 1 more migration script, run `php artisan migrate`, then I started to see this error.

Comment: @NinoArmani : Do u have postgres as your database ? OR mysql ?

Comment: I have faced this issue in both

Comment: Wow. How did u manage to go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual solution is to append `'schema'   => 'public',` to the end of the psql DB_CONNECTION.

```
'pgsql'       => [
    'driver'      => 'pgsql',
    'host'        => env('DB_HOST'),
    'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'     => 'utf8',
    'collation'   => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'      => '',
    'strict'      => false,
    'schema'   => 'public', <------- ADD HERE
    ],
```

---

Now, `php artisan migrate` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

It is an old question but i faced this problem recently and it seems after copying my migration table from another database owner is changed.

So check your database and table owners and make sure tables owned by same user.

Comment: And where do you start checking? I have my project hosted on Heroku

Comment: You can check with this command;

`SELECT *
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND 
    schemaname != 'information_schema';`

Comment: Same issue here.. when copying production db to staging the tables in the staging still had the owner of the production db.

After copying the db I run this command on the new staging db:
`REASSIGN OWNED BY production_user TO staging_user;`